# jQuery when to use next, find, closest?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select the closest show_data div the toggle_container div... However nothing gets selected.

html:

```
<div class="section_header">
    HEADER
    <div class="toggle_container">
        Hide
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show_data">
    HEADER <span id="show_viewed_link">Show</span>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(".show_data").css("display", "none");
$(".toggle_container").live('click', function () 
{
    if ($.trim($(this).html()) === 'Hide') 
    {
        $(this).parent().slideUp("normal");
        $(this).parent().closest(".show_data").css("display", "block");
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $(this).parent().slideDown("normal");
        $(this).parent().closest(".show_data").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Comment: reading docs carefully will clear your all doubts. And title and question body asking for two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need siblings:-

Closest does the search traversing up the DOM tree but here `show_data` is not ancestor of `toggle_container`. It is a sibling of its parent.

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".show_data").css("display", "block");
```

instead of:-

```
$(this).parent().closest(".show_data").css("display", "block");
```

*From Doc*

#### Closest

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

#### Siblings

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.